# Run mysql command in background

Tags: paramiko, mysql

Is there any way to run mysql command in background or keep the connection alive for some time where in there can be queries executed on it.
Can nohup be used to achieve this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are, you can do this with [ajax](http://web.bearsols.com/development-design/javascript/running-queries-in-the-background-with-a-mysql-client-with-ajax-by-alejandro-gervasio)

With Nohup you can do this

```
mysql -u [username] -p [database_name] -e "[sql_query]"
```

Example:

```
nohup mysql -u root -p somedb -e "select * from mytable" &
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But this will close the connection as soon as the query is executed . I want the connection to be alive for some time

Comment: please see http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/12/22/running-process-in-the-background-with-nohup/

Comment: okay, I am using that command to execute on a remote machine using paramiko and exec_command in python and that is failing to launch the process